# Node.js transform my functions to async/await pattern, because data which I want to use is Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I am using node.js express

First I want to read and parse csv file with fast-csv/parse npm package and later I want to use this data in other function, where I will later create Excel file.

I keep getting undefined when I console.log(parsedData) in my other function..
I returned my code to the previous state, so it is not messed up anymore with my tries.

```
var Excel = require("exceljs");

var fs = require("fs");
var csv = require("@fast-csv/parse");

let parsedData: any;

fs.createReadStream("./utilities/test.csv")
  .pipe(csv.parse())
  .on("error", (error: any) => console.log("Error"))
  .on("data", (row: any) => {
    let line: any = String(row);
    line = line.split(";");
    let parsedData = line[0];
    console.log(parsedData);
  })
  .on("end", (rowCount: any) => console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`));

module.exports.generateExcel = async () => {
  // Here i want variable parsedData from the createReadStream function


  /* --------------------------------------------------------------------
  functionaliti about creating excel (it doesn't matter for my question)
   -------------------------------------------------------------------- */

  let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
  workbook.xlsx.readFile("./utilities/template.xlsx").then(() => {
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    let row = worksheet.getRow(5);
    row.getCell(5).value = 5;
    row.commit();
    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile("./utilities/new.xlsx");
  });
};
```

Thanks to everyone for help.

Comment: simply because you doesnt return anything in your `generateExcel` function

Comment: You have _two_ variables `parsedData`, a global one which you don't use, and a local one, which contains data from one row only. If you rename the global variable to `allParsedData = []`, you can write `allParsedData.push(parsedData)` in the "on-data" handler and call `generateExcel(allParsedData)` in the "on-end" handler.

Comment: You cave to _call_ `generateExcel` with `parsedData` as an argument from the `.on('end', ...` callback.

Comment: When and where is `exports.generateExcel` called? Do you want to read the csv file at that point (every time `generateExcel` is called), or do you want to read the file with static data only once?

Comment: generate excel is for now called on index.ts for testing purposes. I want to read file every time the excel is called, because later on this files will be changing